# Service worker is not working in offline mode

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching, angular-service-worker

I have followed the angular documentation on service worker and I am able to run the project offline on the local machine. When I try to deploy to Github pages, it's working fine in online mode and I am also able to see files are fetched through service workers in network and service worker is running in application tab but when I try to reload the page in offline mode it's not working.

https://github.com/PrithiviRajG/Angular-Service-Worker is my Github account
https://prithivirajg.github.io/Angular-Service-Worker/ is my Github page

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is an issue, with Service Worker functionality, in the latest Angular release (`5.2.7`). [More info can be found here.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8779)

Try to change your dependencies from `^5.2.0` to `5.2.0` (exact match)

Here you can check working example: [Angular PWA](https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-pwa) and [Angular Universal PWA - live demo](https://www.angular-universal-pwa.maciejtreder.com)